# Setting amount on capture of pre-auth payment, apparently "amount" is not a parameter

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to call the stripe.Charge.retrieve function

```
ch = stripe.Charge.retrieve(id = charge_id, amount=total_cost)
response = ch.capture()
```

but it throws "InvalidRequestError: Received unknown parameter: amount", even though the API reference in the docs say it does support the parameter amount. (https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_capture) The same thing happens when I try application_fee or receipt_email, which are the other two optional parameters, so I must've either passed the parameters wrong somehow or the python SDK is broken.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the documentation is confusing because of differences between the REST API and the client libraries. This is one of those times.

The client libraries have you calling a `capture` method on a Charge object. They therefore do not use the id parameter, but will take the optional parameters listed.

So for your use case in Python, your code would look something like this:

```
response = ch.capture(amount=4200)
```

The sample code is also intended to be fully-functional, which can confuse things even more in cases like these. The call to `retrieve` is unrelated to capturing funds; it's there so you have a Charge object to call `capture` on. Whenever you're in doubt about something in the Stripe API, let the verbs lead you; they've been selected to be as self-explanatory as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! The biggest thing that confused me was because stripe.Charge.create() takes "amount", and when I skimmed through the code in the actual module, retrieve() seemed to take an arbitrary number of arguments.